# How i can order the query on time

Tags: mysql, time, sql-order-by

```
select playing_time from video order by playing_time desc;
```

The column type of `playing_time` is `varchar(25)`
Sample Data

```
01:05:22  
21:08  
07:52  
04:31
```

The query dont work it does not order by highest time
how i can solve this problem ?

Comment: What column type is playing_time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for changing the column type used for storing the duration from `varchar` to `unsigned int` and hold the length in seconds. This way you know exactly what you have stored there. Right now, you have to treat differently the (at least) 2 formats you have there: (21:08 and 01:05:22)

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
SELECT playing_time FROM video ORDER BY str_to_date(playing_time,'%k:%s') DESC
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format